# Does an ESX hypervisor report stolen time correctly to linux guests

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi

I have a bunch of debian 8 guests running on an esxi 6 hypervisor. `top` seems to always report 0 for its steal time counter. Is the stolen time reporting supposed to work when linux runs on esxi hypervisors. A recording of cpu steal time made by `telegraf` confirms I only get zeros.

I am trying to explain a bunch of time holes in application logs and nothing seems wrong other than that.

Comment: The short answer is no, based on https://serverfault.com/a/1031849/105928